# need help to get inverse kinematics

Tags: robotic-arm

I have a 3 degree of freedom arm robot and by using D-H representation method get the forward kinematics but I can't derive the inverse kinematics can someone help me please ?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* mustafa, but I'm afraid that it is not clear what you are asking. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it's a good idea to include details of what you want to achieve, **what you tried, what you saw & what you expected to see.** Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: Please *edit your question* to show all the work you've done so far, including what you tried to do to get the inverse kinematics and why you think it might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The D-H-representation is a good starting point for an inverse kinematics solver. Usually, DH means, that the joints of the kinematic chain are stored in a matrix. This can be converted into an array in computer code. As a result, the forward model can be built. A forward model takes as input the angle of the joints and prints out the xy-coordinates for each link. The xy-coordinates can be copied to the graphics engine which will display the kinematic chain to the screen.

So the open question is how to use the forward model in the inverse direction? That means, the solver gets the x/y coordinates and should calculate the angles for each joint. At first let me explain which technique doesn't work. Calculating the values with algebra equations isn't a good choice. It might work for simpler models, but if the kinematic chain gets more complicated and has some underactuation in it, the equation will fail to return the correct values. The better way is a sampling approach. The existing forward model is used by a sampling based solver to determine the angles with trial and error. A possible sampling technique is Monte-carlo-tree-search.

[image: inverse kinematics]

Answer (score 0):

For a three DOF arm the IK is pretty simple. 
You can find a closed form with a bunch of sin / cosine operations to derive the angles for a given TCP pose directly.

If you are too lazy to do the math, have a look at OpenRAVE's IK-Fast. It is an open source lib that can generate IK solvers for almost all kinematic types.